# Playing a sound from a button in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know this is a topic covered a lot on the web, but I'm really frustrated right now.

I'm using ASP 3.5, and I want to play an audio .wav file when a user clicks a button on my website. Should be quite simple right?

This is my code:

This JavaScript function is placed in an asp:Content block. I've verified that it's correct, other js functions work.

```
function playSound() {
            document.getElementById("soundDummy").innerHTML = "<embed src='file.wav' autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>";
            return true;
        }
```

soundDummy is a random div with nothing in it.

However, the button is generated in my code behind.

```
audioScript = "<input type=\"image\" src=\"images/Audio_Icon_Small.jpg\" onclick=\"playSound('" + person.audioName + ".wav')\" style=\"border-width:0px;\" />";
```

I do this because its a website with a lot of different people "profiles" so t speak, and I want a person to be able to click a button and hear a .wav file associated with them.

When I click the button, the page just refreshes, and nothing plays. Any suggestions?

Edit: Sorry, there's some discrepancy that I'm passing in a parameter within the button, and my playSound() doesn't take a method. I was playing around with the playSound() method and changed it so it doesn't take a parameter right now, but imagine that it does.

Edit2: Apologies again, but the audioScript is written onto the page using Response.Write(audioScript)

Edit3: Okay, figured it out! I think it was due to my own stupidity, so sorry to all those who tried to help me (especially Josh :/)

So the issue was that my Response.Write(audioScript) which makes my button was not in my soundDummy div. I had for some reason thought that I could put my button generation in a different div than the one I embedded the html from my javascript function in. So now it looks kind of like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
   <p>
      <div id="soundDummy">
         <% Response.Write(audioScript); %>
      </div>
```

as opposed to:

```
<div id="soundDummy"></div>
<div style="text-align: center">
   <p>
       <% Response.Write(audioScript); %>
```

If anyone could tell me why the first one works, but the second doesn't, that'd be great! But as for now, I'm just happy it finally plays a sound :).

Comment: Is there an `<a>` element in there somewhere we can't see?

Comment: when you right click > view source on your web page, is the element's ID actually "soundDummy" or is it something like master_content_soundDummy?

Comment: Sorry I've been editing because I just realized things in <> don't show up. And the element's ID is actually soundDummy, the master content stuff is what happens when the object is dynamically generated right?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with asp.net.

Comment: And based on below posts, you've already removed postback, so the JS has a chance to fire, which makes me think typo? Take a look at http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm , the syntax is slightly different and includes quotations, your DocType may care.  Also try eye-balling your source for typos, use the web console (firefox), or run it through w3c validation.

Comment: Nick - Apologies if that's the case. I thought to tag it because I'm using the asp elements and the code behind with a Response.Write(). And I'll rescan my code again, going to feel really silly if its a typo (been trying to get this t work for a few hours now haha.)

Answer (score 1):

When you click on that element, the browser thinks you are trying to submit a form.

You need to prevent the event from bubbling up. This can be done by returning false, or using [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault).

Preventing event propogation is not implemented consistently across all browsers, so I would recommend using jQuery, but here is a quick fiddle that proves the point:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/S2vhX/

```
<form>Will Submit
    <input id="will" type='image' src='' />Won't Submit
    <input id="wont" type='image' src='' />
</form>

(function () {

    function stopDefAction(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    document.getElementById('wont').addEventListener(
        'click', stopDefAction, false);

}());
```

And here is a working example of using jQuery to play sounds (without submitting the form):

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/CtFRY/

```
<form>
    Sword Slash
    <input class="playsound" type='image' src=''  
           data-audio-url='http://noproblo.dayjo.org/ZeldaSounds/LOZ/LOZ_Sword.wav' />
    Shield
    <input class="playsound" type='image' src='' 
           data-audio-url='http://noproblo.dayjo.org/ZeldaSounds/LOZ/LOZ_Shield.wav' />
    <audio id="playTarget" src="" autoplay style="display:none">
</form>

(function () {

    $(".playsound").on("click", function (e) {
        var url = $(this).data("audio-url");

        $("#playTarget").attr("src", url);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

}());
```

Comment: I've tried changing it to return false; nothing happens though :/

return false; prevents postback correct? I've tried running the method as onClientClick = "playSound(); return false;" and that doesn't work as well.

Comment: The page refreshing is normal behavior when using a submit button. Which is what type='image' basically is... a graphical submit button. You have to prevent the default behavior of submitting the page back to the server.

Comment: Alright, gotcha. How do I go about preventing that? Return False; at the end of the javascript function seems to still make it refresh (and no sound plays either).

Comment: @user2146181 - See my updates for something that will hopefully get you rolling in the right direction.

Comment: Hey thanks! I definitely appreciate the effort, I'll try it out. I 'd upvote you but apparently I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: @user2146181 - Yeah you need at least 15 rep for that. You can certainly mark it as "accepted" though if it works out for you :)